# Salesforce CPQ Renewal Quote and Document Generation Automation

Tags: cpq, quote-template

I'm working on a requirement to automatically generate renewal opp/quote , then generate document and email to customer .

The logic I followed is as follows:

1. Wrote a batch class that would pick Contracts up for Renewal before
   Contract Ends.
2. Schedule batch class at a particular time every day.
3. For document generation, reps has to manually mark a checkbox field 
   on Contract. When this is checked , on my Batch execute I have a
   conditional block inside which I update the quote created(with
   values    on email template, quote template id ,etc ; required for
   document    generation) , enqueue a Queueable which calls the
   calculator api    inside its execute . On the calculator api , I 
   execute the    MassQuoteDocumentSender batch which generates
   document and emails the    same to the customer.

Till now this is working fine but I have some doubts.

My questions are:

1. Am I following the correct process?
2. I still do not understand the use of QueueableCalculatorService, why does it run everytime a contract is renewal forecasted/quoted , what is its purpose? Because I don't know when the above queueable would end I called the calculator api and when it is done I generate the document on its callback.

Below is code for start and execute block . Note that batch size would be 1 as suggested by Salesforce:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){

    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        //Get suitable Contracts for Renewal Opp and Quote creation
        'SELECT Id ,SBQQSC__Quote__r.SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c,Auto_Renewal__c,SBQQSC__RenewalForecast__c ,SBQQSC__RenewalQuoted__c,Renewed_By_System__c FROM ServiceContract WHERE SBQQSC__RenewalForecast__c = FALSE AND SBQQSC__RenewalQuoted__c = FALSE AND Service_Contract_Up_for_Renewal__c = TRUE AND Renewed_By_System__c = FALSE'
    );
}

/*
* Method Name   : execute
* Description   : This method sets Renewal Forecasted and Renewal Quoted to TRUE on the suitable Service Contracts. This is required for Renewal Opp and Quote creation.
* Parameter(s)  : Database.BatchableContext , List<ServiceContract>
* Return Type   : void
*/

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<ServiceContract> scope){

    ServiceContract contract = scope[0];

    //Create Renewal Opportunity
    contract.SBQQSC__RenewalForecast__c = TRUE;
    //Create Renewal Quote
    contract.SBQQSC__RenewalQuoted__c = TRUE;
    //Check Renewed by System flag to indicate that Opportunity / Quote has been created by Batch
    contract.Renewed_By_System__c = TRUE;

    try{
        update contract;

        System.debug('Allowed 1 ' + Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs());
        System.debug('No of jobs added on queue 1 ' + Limits.getQueueableJobs());
    }

    catch(DMLException e){
        ExceptionHandler.insertException('Service Contract','RenewContractsBatch','execute method on renew contracts batch',''+e.getCause(),'execute method on renew contracts batch',e.getMessage() , String.valueOf(e.getLineNumber()) , e.getTypeName(),'',contract.Id,'while renewing contract through batch','');
    }




    if(contract.Auto_Renewal__c){

        SBQQ__Quote__c quote = [ SELECT Id,SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c,SBQQ__Status__c,SBQQ__QuoteTemplateId__c,SBQQ__EmailTemplateId__c,SBQQ__DocumentStatus__c FROM SBQQ__Quote__c WHERE SBQQ__Opportunity2__r.SBQQSC__RenewedServiceContract__c =: contract.Id ];
        //update quote for document generation
        quote.SBQQ__Status__c = 'Approved';
        quote.SBQQ__QuoteTemplateId__c = '****'; //some id
        quote.SBQQ__EmailTemplateId__c = '***'; //some id
        quote.SBQQ__DocumentStatus__c = 'Pending';
        quote.SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c = contract.SBQQSC__Quote__r.SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c;

        try{
            update quote;

            QuoteReader reader = new QuoteReader();
            QuoteModel readQuote = reader.read(quote.Id);

            QuoteCalculatorQueueable calculator = new QuoteCalculatorQueueable(readQuote, 'CalculateCallback');
            System.enqueueJob(calculator);

            System.debug('Allowed 2 ' + Limits.getLimitQueueableJobs());
            System.debug('No of jobs added on queue 2 ' + Limits.getQueueableJobs());
        }
        catch(Exception e){             
            ExceptionHandler.insertException('Service Contract','RenewContractsBatch','execute method on renew contracts batch',''+e.getCause(),'execute method on renew contracts batch',e.getMessage() , String.valueOf(e.getLineNumber()) , e.getTypeName(),'',contract.Id,'while renewing contract through batch' + '.' + 'Note that this is for Auto Renewal flow.' ,'');      
        }            
    }
}
```

Calculator Queuable:

```
public class QuoteCalculator implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {

public QuoteModel quote;
String callbackClass;

public QuoteCalculator(QuoteModel quote, String callbackClass){
    this.quote = quote;
    this.callbackClass = callbackClass;
}

public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    QuoteCalculatorContext ctx = new QuoteCalculatorContext(quote, callbackClass);
    SBQQ.ServiceRouter.load('SBQQ.QuoteAPI.QuoteCalculator', null, JSON.serialize(ctx));        
}

    public class QuoteCalculatorContext {        
    public QuoteModel quote;
    public String callbackClass;        

    public QuoteCalculatorContext(QuoteModel quote, String callbackClass) {
      this.quote = quote;            
      this.callbackClass = callbackClass;        
    }
    }
    }
```

Callback:

```
global with sharing class CalculateCallback implements SBQQ.CalculateCallback {

global void callback(String quoteJSON){

    SBQQ.ServiceRouter.save('SBQQ.QuoteAPI.QuoteSaver', quoteJSON); 


    SBQQ.MassQuoteDocumentSender generateDocBatch = new SBQQ.MassQuoteDocumentSender();
    Database.executeBatch(generateDocBatch,1);


}


}
```

Comment: It would help to see snippets of the code you're describing. Have you seen this [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000267468&language=en_US&type=1) that outlines the steps with sample code in the logic you're referring to?

Comment: @AyoolaOlapo have updated the question with code snippets! Yes I did go through the help article before implementing this.